# ListPreference Dialog Title does not show

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference, preferencescreen

I can not see the title of the ListPreference when I open the list popup. I use `android:dialogTitle="nectionType"`  but Nothing is shown top of the dialog title.

Any suggestion why could this happen? Thanks.

The xml code I use:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="deneme1"
        android:key="deneme1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="cConnectionType"
            android:title="BANANA2"
            android:summary="OMG"
            android:dialogTitle="nectionType"
            android:entries="@array/syncFrequency"
            android:entryValues="@array/syncFrequencyValues"
            android:defaultValue="99" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you modify your styles.xml? If yes please edit it in your question above.

Comment: Thanks I found the mistake I made. The root of the style has "NoActionBar". That was the problem. Thanks again, cheers :)